# Kotlin Array/List extractor in Pattern Matching

Tags: arrays, scala, kotlin, pattern-matching, extractor

In Scala one can extract array elements in a pattern matching statement. For example, I want to take the first two elements of a string input:

```
  private def parseFieldSize(s: String): Option[(Int, Int)] =
    try {
      s.split(" ").map(_.toInt) match {
        case Array(x, y, _*) => Some(x, y)
        case _ => None
      }
    } catch {
      case _: NumberFormatException => None
    }
```

How do I do the same in Kotlin? The closest I can get is:

```
   private fun parseFieldSize(s: String): Pair<Int, Int>? =
      try {
        val inputInts = s.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
        if (2 == inputInts.size)
          Pair(inputInts[0], inputInts[1])
        else
          null
      } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        null
      }
```

Comment: Kotlin doesn't really have pattern matching. In some cases you can use destructuring like this: `val (s1, s2) = s.split(" ")`, but neither this feature nor `when` can't be called a pattern matching, as in Scala. We have to extract the data manually.

Comment: @pumpump You could do this in one line in the 'try' clause: _s.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }.let { it[0] to it[1] }_